# Photoshop Script: Get color of Rectangle Shape and Solid Fill layers

Tags: javascript, photoshop

In my project I have some Rectangle Shape layers and one Solid Fill layer. I need to print out colors of those layers.

This code enumerates all layers and prints names of visible:

```
#target photoshop

for (var i = (app.activeDocument.artLayers.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    var layer = app.activeDocument.artLayers[i]
    if (layer.visible)
    {
        $.writeln(layer)
    }
}
```

How can I get colors? Layers may be transparent.